# How to pause Matlab executable and resume it from Terminal

Tags: bash, matlab

I'm writing an application in Servoy that calls a Matlab executable to perform some complicated mathematical operations and turn the results back to a database.

The problem is that Matlab executables are quite slow especially when they start.

I would like to start the executable when I perform the first operation, then pause it in the background and call it again when needed.
I can perform calls to the Terminal from Servoy, but I don't know how to make Matlab pause and resume (if it is possible at all).

I'm looking forward to any suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

In theory you could work with your existing bash solution, use `input` to pause matlab and type in any key to continue, but I strongly recommend not to do so.

There are two good ways to go, first you could build a library instead of an executable. The Matlab Builder JA allows you to export your functionality as a jar file.

Further you could create an application server (executable) which allows to call methods via XMLRPC or similar protocols. Here I am not sure what functionality is available when deploying to an executable, it might be that you have to chose some alternative to XMLRPC.

Both possibilities allow you to split up your task into individual steps, calling them one by one whenevery you want to proceed.

Comment: I tried your first suggestion but when I try to export my file i get an error:"Only matlab functions and MEX files with a single entry point are acceptable files. My knowhow of Matlab is very little. What I'm trying to do is to export an .m file.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not give you detailed help because I no longer have access to the deployment tools.

Answer (score 1):

You can send signals to the process in order to accomplish this:

```
kill -STOP $PID
```

> When SIGSTOP is sent to a process, the usual behaviour is to pause that process in its current state. The process will only resume execution if it is sent the SIGCONT signal. SIGSTOP and SIGCONT are used for job control in the Unix shell, among other purposes. SIGSTOP cannot be caught or ignored.

To resume:

```
kill -CONT $PID
```

> When SIGSTOP or SIGTSTP is sent to a process, the usual behaviour is to pause that process in its current state. The process will only resume execution if it is sent the SIGCONT signal. SIGSTOP and SIGCONT are used for job control in the Unix shell, among other purposes.

More info [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_control_%28Unix%29#Implementation)